# Android Alpha Update - No Download Showing

Tags: android, google-play

I've recently released an Alpha build of my app via Google Play Console (as I've done many times in the past). This is a closed testing build and I've opted in with my device/account via the URL console provides.

There is an existing production version of the app.

I waited a little while then went to PlayStore app to download the update. 
Strange thing is, the version shown in PlayStore is updated (to the one used by my Alpha build) but there is no option to 'Update', only the option to Open the already installed (older) production version I have installed on my phone.

Has anyone seen this before? Could it just be Google are still in the process of rolling out my Alpha build?

**Update**

- I've waited over 12 hours now since upload to console
- I've tried clearing the cache on the PlayStore app to see if the update option appears but it didn't.

**Update 2**

- I've got the update to work but in a very convoluted way. I had to:

  - Open the 'download' link on the testing opt-in page using Chrome (not PlayStore)
  - Click 'Buy' (not Update) and let it install

The result is though that it didn't *seem* to update the app, rather overwrite it. As a result a migration routine I had in the new app to pull over old data didn't run and my previous app data was lost (this is a separate issue though).

It does sound like something is wrong with my PlayStore app but what!?

Comment: How long did you wait? It can be a few hours until everything is synced up.

Comment: I guess that's just a caching issue in the Play Store app. Clear cache and re-open the app (you can also just update from the "my apps" section, without tapping the app)

Comment: I should have said - I initially waited 4 hours but it's been >12 hours now

Comment: @ByteHamster ok great - i'll try that. Very weird - never seen that before! Will let you know how I get on

Comment: @ByteHamster doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. This sounds like you changed package name (essentially released a new app) rather than just release a new Alpha.

Comment: No, not a new package name as the update appeared as the app already listed on the PlayStore (but only via Chrome, not the PlayStore app) and when it installed it overwrote the existing app too. Very weird!

Comment: I'd contact Play developer support via the Play console for this one, they have much more detail available to them, and will be able to help more easily.

Comment: noted...good idea. Im going to roll out a new alpha build later so I'm hoping it was just a local cache issue of some kind and the issue will resolve itself